# typing for rare case fallback None value

Tags: python, typing

Trying to avoid typing issues I often run into the same problem.

E.g. I have a function `x` that very rarily returns value `None`, all other times it returns `int`.

```py
def x(i: int) -> Union[int, None]:
    if i == 0:
        return
    return i

def test(i: int):
    a = x(i)
    # typing issue: *= not supported for types int | None and int
    a *= 25
```

`x` used very often in the codebase and most of the time `i` was already checked a hundred times that `x(i)` will indeed return `int` and not `None`.
Using it as `int` right away creates typing warnings - e.g. you can't multiply possible `None` value.

What's best practice for that case?

Ideas I considered:

1. There is no real sense to check it for `None` with `if a is None: return` as it's already *known*.
2. `a *= 25 # type: ignore` will make `a` an `Unknown` type.
3. `a = x(i) # type: int` will make the warning go away. But will create a new warning "int | None cannot be assigned to int"
4. `a = cast(int, x(i))`, haven't tested it much yet.

I usually end up changing return type of `x` to just `int`, adding `ignore` in `return # type: ignore` and mention in the docstring that it can return `None`, it helps avoiding contaminating the entire codebase with type warnings. Is this the best approach?

```py
def x(i: int) -> int:
    """might also return `None`"""
    if i == 0:
        return # type: ignore
    return i
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a case where an exception is better than a return statement you never expect to be reached.

```
def x(i: int) -> int:
    if i == 0:
        raise ValueError("didn't expect i==0")
    return i

def test(i: int):
    try:
        a = x(i)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    a *= 25
```

Code that is confident it has sufficiently validated the argument to `x` can omit the `try` statement.

Statically speaking, this is accurate: *if* `x` returns, it is guaranteed to return an `int`. (Whether it will return is another question.)

---

Ideally, you could define a refinement type like `NonZeroInt`, and turn `i == 0` into a type error, rather than a value error.

```
# Made-up special form RefinementType obeys
#
#  isinstance(x, RefinementType[T, p]) == isinstance(x, T) and p(x)
NonZeroInt = RefinementType[int, lambda x: x != 0]

def x(i: NonZeroInt) -> int:
    return i

x(0)  # error: Argument 1 to "x" has incompatible type "int"; expected "NonZeroInt"  [arg-type]

i: int = 0
x(i)  # same error

j: NonZeroInt = 0  #  error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "NonZeroInt")  [assignment]

x(j)  # OK

k: NonZeroInt = 3  # OK
x(k)  # OK
```

Comment: You can also frame this as a thought experiment: if you aren't comfortable replacing a static type check with a runtime exception, you're not as sure that the argument `i` has been checked as carefully as you are assuming.

Comment: > Code that is confident it has sufficiently validated the argument to x can omit the try statement.



That's very good point. And it's also better to throw exception for it to fail right away instead of letting it work and break in some lest expected place.

Comment: Of course, "fail right away" really means "fail when you finally execute `x(0)`", which may not happen until the second, third, ..., twentieth, ... time you run your code. The benefit of the static type check is that it can catch errors that might hide for a long time. My tangent on `NonZeroInt` is my attempt at assuaging my guilt for replacing a static error with a runtime error :)